# Etwas zu etwas gehört

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

Could you please help me with ways to complete this sentence?

> Zu meinen besonderen Interessen (in meinem Studienfach) gehörten/ gehören vor allem …...

My dictionary tells me that "X zu Y gehört" can mean "Y owns X" or "X is a part of Y" or "X is a prerequisite to Y", but I'm not sure which meaning is used in the sentence above...

Answer (score 3):

> Etwas gehört zu etwas/jemandem (a)

(note the "zu", and look for a better dictionary if yours doesn't point out the difference) means something different than

> Etwas gehört etwas/jemandem (b)

(b) is about ownership only.

(a) mainly means "x is part of y" (I) or "x is a prerequisite of y" (II)

In your specific example, (II) doesn't make a lot of sense (because subtopics can't be a prerequisite to interests), so it must be (I).

You would translate as something like

> x, y, z were amongst my interests...

Answer (score 3):

"X gehört zu Y" can also mean something like "X belongs to category Y" or "X is a member of group Y". For example,

> Die Hunde gehören zu den Säugetieren.

> Dogs belong to (the category of) the mammals.

or

> Er gehört zu den Anfängern in seinem Tennisverein.

> He is a part of (the group of) the beginners in his tennis club.

or

> Sie gehört zu den größten in ihrer Klasse.

> She is a part of (the group of) the tallest (students) in her class.

So,

> Zu meinen besonderen Interessen (in meinem Studienfach) gehörten/ gehören vor allem...

means something along the lines of

> Among my special interests (in my field of study) were / are especially...